# Uploading file(images,videos,.docx,.pdf,...) via REST API

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, rest, multifile-uploader

I'm working with Asp.Net Core WebApi and I want to develop a file manager service to upload files to the server and some metadata to the SQL Server(like uploadDate or fileUploaderUserId) table and also store file location in "Files" table,so is it okay to use REST API to upload heavy files like videos (size:between 50Mb and 1024Mb)? if it's not, what is the best way??
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes it is okay but really it depends on what you want to do - but you can use a REST API to upload sizes between 50-1024MB;

Comment: It is a File Manager Service that will be one of the services of a Microservice project,i want to do all file uploading task from another service by this service

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.